# protractor in typescript setup issue

Tags: typescript, protractor, visual-studio-code

Tried running protractor with typescript, but got following error

```
C:\MyFiles\NewTechonologies\Protractor\TypeScript\Test>npm install
npm ERR! not a package C:\Users\skp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\skp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "
install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\Users\skp\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-8952-eac08724\unpack-b2acb3b1\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\skp\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-8952-eac08724\unpac
k-b2acb3b1\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\skp\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-8952-eac08724\unpac
k-b2acb3b1\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\MyFiles\NewTechonologies\Protractor\TypeScript\Test\npm-debug.log
```

My setup is like
[image: config.ts]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "example-typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a typescript example",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "pretest": "npm run tsc",
    "test": "C:/Users/skp/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor tmp/conf.js",
   "debug": "node --inspect --debug-brk C:/Users/skp/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor asyncAwait/conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "protractor": "C:/Users/skp/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

spec.ts

```
import {browser, element, by, By, $, $$, ExpectedConditions} from 'protractor';

describe('protractor with typescript typings', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
  });

  it('should greet the named user', () => {
    element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');
    let greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));
    expect(greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
  });

  it('should list todos', function() {
    let todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(2);
    expect(todoList.get(1).getText()).toEqual('build an angular app');
  });
});
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "tmp"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "asyncAwait",
    "plugins.ts"
  ]
}
```

I have installed protractor, jasmine, typescript globally.
still getting error as above and conf.ts also throws error on protractor text as shown in picture
Please guide where exactly the setup went wrong.

Comment: I know this is from ages ago, but why install protractor and jasmine globally?  You can run the locally-installed versions easily using an NPM package task or `npx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have installed the above said modules globally, they should work without the npm install.

Nevertheless, you should have these modules as dependencies in your package.json. It clearly is a path issue, npm is not able to find the protractor module during `npm install`.

You have 2 options -

- correct the local protractor path in your package.json

  ```
  "dependencies": {
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.0",
  "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
  "protractor": "C:/Users/skp/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor",
  "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  },
  ```
- mention the protractor version in package.json as you have done with rest of your modules

  ```
  "dependencies": {
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.0",
  "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
  "protractor": "^5.1.1",
  "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  },
  ```

Now if you run ``npm install` it should install the dependencies successfully.

Comment: now npm install works fine, but getting error while npm test to run the test

node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(26,41): error TS2314: Generic type 'Matchers<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(27,39): error TS2314: Generic type 'Matchers<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(152,24): error TS2314: Generic type 'Matchers<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

Comment: This is a different issue, if the above answer solved your previous issue please accept it as it would help others who could face the same issue.

Comment: You next issue seems to be more related to typescript not identifying the jasmine typings, I would need more info to debug this . I would suggest to raise a new issue so that it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `npm install` after giving the dependies.

```
//conf.ts
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
  //specs: ['../Tests/LoginTestCases.js'],



  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};


//Package.json
{
  "name": "newprotractor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
       "@types/node": "12.12.2",
    "jasmine": "3.5.0",
       "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "^0.0.7",
    "ts-node": "8.5.4",
    "typescript": "3.4.3",
    }
}
```

With the command `npm install`, your protractor will install for your current project and then your error will be gone